# I'd like to show new page per a group in ssrs. Please check my images below

Tags: reporting-services

I'd like to show new page per a group in ssrs. Please check my images below[image]

How to set to show one group box per page?

Answer (score 1):

The third section of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is titled "To add a page break to a row group in a table, matrix, or list" and should have what you are looking for.